# Getting the attribute of an element dynamically?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I dont know how to search for this, so apologies if this has been asked before. Basically i am using jQuery/AJAX/PHP to dynamically save to a database, pull info back etc. I have made my form save and pull back the room's id, and then the item's id's when they are saved, however i need a way to dynamically save the room id to it's children items so it all links up in the database. I will try and explain everything i can.

```
<div id="formHolder" rel="1">
            <form class="rooms">
                <label>Room</label>
                <input type="text" name="roomName[]">
                <input type="hidden" class="roomId" name="roomId[]">
                <input type="hidden" class="inventoryId" name="inventoryId[]" value="<?=$_GET['inventory_id']?>">
                <div class="saveRoom">Save Room</div>
            </form>
            <div class="addItem">
                <form class="items">
                    <label>Item</label>
                    <input type="text" name="itemName[]">
                    <label>Description</label>
                    <textarea name="itemDescription[]"></textarea>
                    <label>Condition</label>
                    <select name="itemCondition[]">
                        <option value="Good">Good</option>
                        <option value="Adequate">Adequate</option>
                        <option value="Poor">Poor</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type="hidden" class="itemId" name="itemId[]" value="">
                    <input type="hidden" name="itemInventoryId[]" value="<?=$_GET['inventory_id']?>">
                    <input type="hidden" name="itemParent[]" value="">
                    <div class="saveIcon" style="display: none; color: green;">SAVED!</div>
                    <div class="save">Save Item</div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div id="addItem">Add another item</div>
        </div>
```

This is the basic form i am using. My plan here was to save the room's ID to the rel attribute and then each item that is added would grab that id from there, but i simply cannot work out how to do it.

```
$('#addItem').on('click', function(){
            $('<form class="items">\
                <label>Item</label>\
                <input type="text" name="itemName[]">\
                <label>Description</label>\
                <textarea name="itemDescription[]"></textarea>\
                <label>Condition</label>\
                <select name="itemCondition[]">\
                    <option value="Good">Good</option>\
                    <option value="Adequate">Adequate</option>\
                    <option value="Poor">Poor</option>\
                </select>\
                <input type="hidden" class="itemId" name="itemId[]" value="">\
                <input type="hidden" name="itemInventoryId[]" value="<?=$_GET["inventory_id"]?>">\
                <input type="hidden" name="itemParent[]" value="'$(this).parent().parent().attr('rel');'">\
                <div class="saveIcon" style="display: none; color: green;">SAVED!</div>\
                <div class="save">Save Item</div>\
            </form>').fadeIn(500).appendTo('.addItem');
        });
```

You can see i've tried using `$(this).parent().parent().attr('rel');` but that doesn't work so i am stumped. I know i've waffled a bit here and if anyone wants to open a chat with me please do, thank you for your time

Comment: whatever you do, or the solution is do never user things like .parent().parent(), one day your code will break and you will spend hours wondering why.

Comment: @bitoiu - would like to +1 your comment one thousand times.

Comment: Still learning jQuery so it's always good to know these things! haha

Comment: @bitoiu - Where were you when I first learned jQuery...

Comment: @tymeJV Lol, probably in the office at 9pm trying to understand why that added span just broke my forms ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will work fine, but you're going up too many levels! The div with the `rel` attr is just the `parent`, not the parents parent:

```
$(this).parent().attr('rel');
```

Or, since your parent has an ID (which better be unique!):

```
$("#formHolder").attr("rel");
```

Comment: will give this a go, 2 secs :)

Comment: That seems to have worked :) I got confused with the DOM tree and thought i was meant to be going up another level! Going to just try some other dynamic stuff quickly but thank you for your help on this

Answer (score 0):

this refers to "#addItem" div and "rel" is an attribute of it's direct parent so i think it should be   just

```
$(this).parent().attr('rel');
```